# Solve $(1+x^2)y'' + y'^2 + 1 = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $(1+x^2)y'' + y'^2 + 1 = 0$

**My Attempt**

Let $p = y'$ and $p' = y''$ then the equation comes of the form:

$$(1+x^2)p' + p^2+1=0 \rightarrow(1+x^2)\frac{dp}{dx} = -(p^2+1)$$
$$\int \frac{-1}{p^2+1}dp = \int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx \rightarrow-\arctan(p)=C + \arctan(x)$$

$$\tan(-\arctan(p))=\tan(C + \arctan(x)) \rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}= -\tan(C+\arctan(x))$$

This integral is rather convoluted, so I am questioning whether there is a mistake / easier approach to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember your trig identites:
$$
\tan(a + b) = \frac{\tan a + \tan b}{1 - \tan a \tan b}.
$$
So this is
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x + C}{1 - Cx},
$$
which can be easily solved with partial fractions.